# How to test controller actions with admin prefix in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, automated-tests

I've been around the block with testing in CakePHP, but am up against a wall when using `testAction()` in Controllers' testing with `admin` prefix.

I've tried `Mock`s, `staticExpects()`, with no luck.

Trying various `return => "contents|vars|view|result"` yielded `null`s. Using `$this->contents` or `$this->view` yields the same.

How to succinctly test controller actions with `admin` prefix, using the least code, preferably in `setUp()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be simple, albeit hard to find.

`$this->generate( 'Posts', [ 'components' => [ 'Auth' ] ] );`

Can be in your test case, in a `setUp()` method, or in some other method for [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.